# How to fix empty array constructor in Julia?

Tags: julia

```
julia> Array(Int8,2,3)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching Array(::Type{Int8}, ::Int64, ::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  Array(::LinearAlgebra.UniformScaling, ::Integer, ::Integer) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.2/LinearAlgebra/src/uniformscaling.jl:395
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[38]:1
```

It's working before update but now is asking for Union.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of defining an array without specifying the value of its elements is the following:

```
julia> Array{Int8}(undef, 2,3)
2×3 Array{Int8,2}:
 0  0  0
 0  0  0
```

Is that what you wanted?

---

There are numerous other ways to define arrays of a certain type, especially when one already knows the values of the elements:

```
julia> zeros(Int8, 2, 3)
2×3 Array{Int8,2}:
 0  0  0
 0  0  0

julia> ones(Int8, 2, 3)
2×3 Array{Int8,2}:
 1  1  1
 1  1  1

julia> Int8[1 2 3; 4 5 6]
2×3 Array{Int8,2}:
 1  2  3
 4  5  6
```

or when you already have an other array with the same type:

```
julia> A = Int8[1 2 3; 4 5 6]
2×3 Array{Int8,2}:
 1  2  3
 4  5  6

julia> similar(A)
# Uninitialized values
2×3 Array{Int8,2}:
  -48   52   -5
 -126  100  127

julia> similar(A, 2, 2)
# Uninitialized values
2×2 Array{Int8,2}:
 -16  -83
   0   94
```